# How do I assemble a hash of hashes piece-wise, not up-front?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures, perl-hash

I want to create a structure of hashes within hashes in Perl, but all tutorials (like chapter 9.4. *Hashes of Hashes* in [Programming Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004927)) add them all upfront. I want to initially create the structure and then fill in the empty hashes using subroutines while I read the file.

For example, I want to read in a book and for each page keep track of words and what lines they appeared on in the page.

The following structure:

```
%Parent = (
    1 => {
        "the" => [1, 4],
        "and" => [2, 3]
    },
    2 => {
        "but" => [1, 2],
        "as"  => [3, 4]
    }
)
```

would mean the word `the` appears on lines 1 and 4 of page 1, `but` appears on lines 1 and 2 of page 2, etc.

How can I do this? Each way I tried to do it I didn't seem to be able to persist my hashes and was losing their values etc.

Comment: Not sure about that edit. I mean, yes, it corrects the problem in the code - but it makes the (correct) answers below look like they haven't read the question correctly :/

Comment: @DaveCross: I did consider that. The code in the question was just an example of the structure the OP wanted and wasn't meant to be executable. Using `()` instead of `[]` is a common mistake and certainly didn't deserve the rant that ikegami gave it, and I think daxim *did* read the question incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

```
"the" => (1, 4), "and" => (2, 3)
```

is a weird way of writing

```
"the", 1, 4, "and", 2, 3
```

which, if assigned to a hash, will be equivalent to

```
%h = ();
$h{"the"} = 1;
$h{4} = "and";
$h{2} = 3;
```

You want

```
%Parent = (
    1 => {
        "the" => [ 1, 4 ],
        "and" => [ 2, 3 ]
    },
    2 => {
        "but" => [ 1, 2 ],
        "as"  => [ 3, 4 ]
    }
)
```

Just like `{ }` creates a hash, assigns the result of the inner expression (if any) to the hash, and returns a reference to that hash, `[ ]` creates an array, assigns the result of the inner expression (if any) to the array, and returns a reference to that array.

---

Of course, none of that answers your question! On to your question.

```
my %Parent = (
    1 => {
        "the" => [1, 4],
        "and" => [2, 3]
    },
    2 => {
        "but" => [1, 2],
        "as"  => [3, 4]
    }
);
```

is basically equivalent to

```
my %Parent;
$Parent{1}{the}[0] = 1;
$Parent{1}{the}[1] = 4;
$Parent{1}{and}[0] = 2;
$Parent{1}{and}[1] = 3;
$Parent{2}{but}[0] = 1;
$Parent{2}{but}[1] = 2;
$Parent{2}{as }[0] = 3;
$Parent{2}{as }[1] = 4;
```

`push` is often more convenient than assignment for populating the arrays. That would look like:

```
my %Parent;
push @{ $Parent{1}{the} }, 1;
push @{ $Parent{1}{the} }, 4;
push @{ $Parent{1}{and} }, 2;
push @{ $Parent{1}{and} }, 3;
push @{ $Parent{2}{but} }, 1;
push @{ $Parent{2}{but} }, 2;
push @{ $Parent{2}{as } }, 3;
push @{ $Parent{2}{as } }, 4;
```

Thanks to autovivification,

```
push @{ $Parent{$k1}{$k2} }, $n;
```

is short for

```
push @{ ( $Parent{$k1} //= {} )->{$k2} //= [] }, $n;
```

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is in assigning a list expression to the word keys in the second level hash. This must be an arrayref instead, e.g. `"the" => [1, 4]`.

```
# assume $page, $line defined
for my $word (@words) {
    push @{ $Parent{$page}{$word} }, $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize $Parent as a var in beginning:

```
my $Parent; # we will use this to store ref of parsed hash
```

Say you are storing page number in $page , word in $word and line in $line
While parsing the file whenever you want to store a new line number you can use code like this:

```
if(exists $Parent->{$page} and $Parent->{$page}->{$word}){
  push( @{ $Parent->{$page}->{$word} },$line);
}else{
  $Parent->{$page}->{$word} = [$line];
}
```

Here we are making sure that if $Parent->{$page}->{$word} has not been initialized yet then initialize it with Anonymous Array first. If it exists then just push the line number into it.